# How do I better perform this numpy calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I have text file something like this:

```
0 0 0 1 2
0 0 1 3 1
0 1 0 4 1
0 1 1 2 3
1 0 0 5 3
1 0 1 1 3
1 1 0 4 5
1 1 1 6 1
```

Let label these columns as:

```
s1 a s2 r t
```

I also have another array with dummy values (for simplicity)

```
>>> V = np.array([10.,20.])
```

I want to do certain calculation on these numbers with good performance. The calculation I want to perform is: for each `s1`, I want max sum `t*(r+V[s1])` for each `a`.
For example,

- for s1=0, a=0, we will have sum = 2*(1+10)+1*(3+10) = 35
- for s1=0, a=1, we will have sum = 1*(4+10)+3*(2+10) = 50

So max of this is 50, which is what I want to obtain as an output for `s1=0`.
Also, note that, in above calculation, 10 is `V[s1]`.

If, I dont have last three lines in file, then, for `s1=1`, I will simply return `3*(5+20)=75`, where `20` is `V[s1]`. So the final desire result is `[50,75]`

So I thought it will be good for numpy to load it as follows (consider values only for s1=0 for simplicity)

```
>>> c1=[[   [ [0,1,2],[1,3,1] ],[ [0,4,1],[1,2,3] ]   ]]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c1arr = np.array(c1)
>>> c1arr  #when I actually load from file, its not loading as this (check Q2 below)
array([[[[0, 1, 2],
         [1, 3, 1]],
        [[0, 4, 1],
         [1, 2, 3]]]])

>>> np.sum(c1arr[0,0][:,2]*(c1arr[0,0][:,1]+V))  #sum over t*(r+V)
45.0
```

**Q1.** I am not able to guess, how can I modify above to get numpy array `[45.0,80.0]`, so that I can get `numpy.max` over it.

**Q2.** When I actually load the file, I am not able load it as `c1arr` as stated in comment above. Instead, am getting it as follows:

```
>>> type(a) #a is populated by parsing file
<class 'list'>

>>> print(a)
[[[[0, -0.9, 0.3], [1, 0.9, 0.6]], [[0, -0.2, 0.6], [1, 0.7, 0.3]]], [[[1, 0.2, 1.0]], [[0, -0.8, 1.0]]]]

>>> np.array(a) #note that this is not same as c1arr above
<string>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
array([[list([[0, -0.9, 0.3], [1, 0.9, 0.6]]),
        list([[0, -0.2, 0.6], [1, 0.7, 0.3]])],
       [list([[1, 0.2, 1.0]]),
        list([[0, -0.8, 1.0]])]], dtype=object)
```

How I can fix this?

**Q3.** Is there any overall better approach, say by laying out the numpy array differently? (Given I am not allowed to use pandas, but only numpy)

Comment: Might http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ be better suited for this?

Comment: @RandomDavis the first two questions would NOT be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the most intuitive and maintainable approach
is to use *Pandas*, where you can assign names to columns.
Another important factor is that grouping is much easier just in *Pandas*.

As your input sample contains only integers, I defined *V*
also as an array of integers:

```
V = np.array([10, 20])
```

I read your input file as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.txt', sep=' ', names=['s1', 'a', 's2', 'r', 't'])
```

(print it to see what has been read).

Then, to get results for each combination of *s1* and *a*,
you can run:

```
result = df.groupby(['s1', 'a']).apply(lambda grp:
    (grp.t * (grp.r + V[grp.s1])).sum())
```

Note that as you refer to named columns, this code is easy to read.

The result is:

```
s1  a
0   0     35
    1     50
1   0    138
    1    146
dtype: int64
```

Each result is **integer** because *V* is also an array of
*int* type. But if you define it just as in your post (an
array of *float*), the result will be also of *float* type
(your choice).

If you want the max result for each *s1*, run:

```
result.max(level=0)
```

This time the result is:

```
s1
0     50
1    146
dtype: int64
```

## The Numpy version

If you **really** are restricted to *Numpy*, there is also a solution,
although more difficult to read and update.

1. Read your input file:

   ```
   data = np.genfromtxt('Input.txt')
   ```

   Initially I tried *int* type, just like in the *pandasonic* solution,
   but one of your comments states that 2 rightmost columns are *float*.
   So, because *Numpy* arrays must be of a **single** type, the whole
   array must be of *float* type.
2. Run the following code:

   ```
   res = []
   # First level grouping - by "s1" (column 0)
   for s1 in np.unique(data[:,0]).astype(int):
       dat1 = data[np.where(data[:,0] == s1)]
       res2 = []
       # Second level grouping - by "a" (column 1)
       for a in np.unique(dat1[:,1]):
           dat2 = dat1[np.where(dat1[:,1] == a)]
           # t - column 4, r - column 3
           res2.append((dat2[:,4] * (dat2[:,3] + V[s1])).sum())
       res.append([s1, max(res2)])
   result = np.array(res)
   ```

The result (a *Numpy* array) is:

```
array([[  0.,  50.],
       [  1., 146.]])
```

The left column contains *s1* values and the right - maximum
group values from the second level grouping.

## The Numpy version with a structured array

Actually, you can also use a *Numpy* structured array.
Then the code is at least more readable, because you refer to column names,
not to column numbers.

Read the array passing *dtype* with column names and types:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(io.StringIO(txt), dtype=[('s1', '<i4'),
    ('a', '<i4'), ('s2', '<i4'), ('r', '<f8'), ('t', '<f8')])
```

Then run:

```
res = []
# First level grouping - by "s1"
for s1 in np.unique(data['s1']):
    dat1 = data[np.where(data['s1'] == s1)]
    res2 = []
    # Second level grouping - by "a"
    for a in np.unique(dat1['a']):
        dat2 = dat1[np.where(dat1['a'] == a)]
        res2.append((dat2['t'] * (dat2['r'] + V[s1])).sum())
    res.append([s1, max(res2)])
result = np.array(res)
```

Comment: I got it that I can use pandas for better, but this isnt doable with only `numpy` ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it also solely with *Numpy*. I added such a solution.

Comment: This looks great. Though I am just curious, does this approach benefits performance-wise from the numpy vectorization? I have this doubt, because I guess mostly we get performance benefit from numpy vectorization if we avoid for loops.

Comment: Avoiding loops is generally a good idea, but unfortunately, *Numpy* has no native *groupby* functionality, like e.g. *Pandas*, so I implemented the grouping using loops. Compare execution times of my first (*pandasonic*) solution, using *groupby* with the second (*numpythonic*) version, on some greater data sample. There are chances that the *pandasonic* solution, without explicit loops, runs faster (contrary to the general rule that *Numpy* code runs faster).

Comment: I was trying to implement above on my actual data which have last two elements as floats. But unable to load them as `[int,int,int,float,float]`. It gets loaded as `[float,float,float,float,float]`. It breaks for `V[s1]` as `s1` is of type `float` and we cant index using `float`. I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402771/how-to-load-numpy-array-with-certain-columns-as-specific-type), if you can / wish to have a look.

Comment: [continuing from my above comment if u havent read it...] will it help in performance to convert all python lists, like `res = []` to numpy array?

Comment: I corrected the *Numpy* version to operate on a *float* array. And concerning you question about *res* as a *Numpy* array: Try, on a larger source data sample, but I suppose that the change will not be significant.