# How to load numpy array with certain columns as specific type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried following:

```
>>> arr2 = [[0, 0, 0, -0.9, 0.3], [0, 0, 1, 0.9, 0.6], [0, 1, 0, -0.2, 0.6], [0, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.3], [1, 0, 1, 0.2, 1.0], [1, 1, 0, -0.8, 1.0]]
>>> narr2 = np.array(arr2)
>>> narr2
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.9,  0.3],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0.9,  0.6],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. , -0.2,  0.6],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.8,  0.3],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0.2,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0. , -0.8,  1. ]])
```

How can I make first three column have type `int`? That is how can I get following:

```
>>> narr2
array([[ 0 ,  0 ,  0 , -0.9,  0.3],
       [ 0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0.9,  0.6],
       [ 0 ,  1 ,  0 , -0.2,  0.6],
       [ 0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  0.8,  0.3],
       [ 1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0.2,  1. ],
       [ 1 ,  1 ,  0 , -0.8,  1. ]])
```

I tried following:

```
>>> narr2 = np.array(arr2,dtype='i4,i4,i4,f8,f8')
>>> narr2
array([[(0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ),
        (0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (0, 0, 0, -0.9, -0.9),
        (0, 0, 0,  0.3,  0.3)],
       [(0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ),
        (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ), (0, 0, 0,  0.9,  0.9),
        (0, 0, 0,  0.6,  0.6)],
       [(0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ),
        (0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (0, 0, 0, -0.2, -0.2),
        (0, 0, 0,  0.6,  0.6)],
       [(0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ),
        (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ), (0, 0, 0,  0.8,  0.8),
        (0, 0, 0,  0.3,  0.3)],
       [(1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ), (0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ),
        (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ), (0, 0, 0,  0.2,  0.2),
        (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. )],
       [(1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ), (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. ),
        (0, 0, 0,  0. ,  0. ), (0, 0, 0, -0.8, -0.8),
        (1, 1, 1,  1. ,  1. )]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

As can be seen, I am not getting the desired output. Seems that I am not understanding how do I specify type while creating array and where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are okay with changing the lists into tuples?

Comment: ohhh I guess below answer does the same, what are implications?

Comment: It seems that with list, I have shape `(6,5)` and with tuple, I have `(6,)`. So cant do numpy vectorized operations involving second dimension indexes. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Right, you can't do math across those fields.  You could set up a dtype that puts the 3 ints in one field, and the floats in another.

Comment: Didnt get you. Also why tuple works as explained in answer, but list does not?

Comment: That's the convention that numpy has chosen for structured arrays.  Input matches output in format.  Have you read the structured arrays doc page?

Comment: You mean [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html)? Nope, I havent read...didnt dig deep in docs.

Comment: ok I guess I understood what you meant by "input matches output". You meant when we convert lists to tuples and then from ndarray out of it, we get tuples inside ndarray, right? But I was asking about why `dtype='i4,i4,i4,f8,f8'` works with tuples but not lists. In other words, I did not get `array([[ 0 ,  0 ,  0 , -0.9,  0.3], ... ])` as explained in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: arr2 = [[0, 0, 0, -0.9, 0.3], [0, 0, 1, 0.9, 0.6], [0, 1, 0, -0.2, 0.6],
   ...:  [0, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.3], [1, 0, 1, 0.2, 1.0], [1, 1, 0, -0.8, 1.0]]
   ...: narr2 = np.array(arr2)
In [2]: dt=np.dtype('i4,i4,i4,f8,f8')
```

With a list of tuples:

```
In [3]: np.array([tuple(l) for l in arr2], dtype=dt)
Out[3]: 
array([(0, 0, 0, -0.9, 0.3), (0, 0, 1,  0.9, 0.6), (0, 1, 0, -0.2, 0.6),
       (0, 1, 1,  0.8, 0.3), (1, 0, 1,  0.2, 1. ), (1, 1, 0, -0.8, 1. )],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

Or with a `recfunctions` utility:

```
In [5]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [6]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(narr2, dt)
Out[6]: 
array([(0, 0, 0, -0.9, 0.3), (0, 0, 1,  0.9, 0.6), (0, 1, 0, -0.2, 0.6),
       (0, 1, 1,  0.8, 0.3), (1, 0, 1,  0.2, 1. ), (1, 1, 0, -0.8, 1. )],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

Comment: does changing lists to tuples limit what we can do?

Comment: It seems that with list, I have shape `(6,5)` and with tuple, I have `(6,)`. So cant do numpy vectorized operations involving second dimension indexes. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you convert lists to tuples, and then assign the data types. Here's my solution:

```
import numpy as np

arr2 = [[0, 0, 0, -0.9, 0.3], [0, 0, 1, 0.9, 0.6], 
[0, 1, 0, -0.2, 0.6], [0, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.3], [1, 0, 1, 0.2, 1.0], [1, 1, 0, -0.8, 1.0]]

tupp2 = [tuple(l) for l in arr2]

datatype = [('A', np.int), ('B', np.int), ('C', np.int), ('D', np.float), ('E', np.float)]
narr2 = np.array(tupp2, dtype=datatype)
```

Checking the data types for each column:

```
for i in narr2[0]:
    print(i.dtype)
```

Gives:

```
int32
int32
int32
float64
float64
```

Comment: this is same as other answer. It seems that with list, I may have shape (6,5) and with tuple, I have (6,). So cant do numpy vectorized operations involving second dimension indexes. Is there any workaround?